# Heroku docker:release: Expected response to be successful, got 422

Tags: heroku, docker

```
heroku docker:release
...
Successfully built b240d9d7bf11
extracting slug from container...
creating remote slug...
language-pack: heroku-docker (ojobot_conda)
remote process types: { web: 'cd /app/user && node server.js' }
uploading slug [====================] 100% of 578 MB, 0.0s
releasing slug...
 !    Error: Expected response to be successful, got 422
```

Not sure what to do next at this point. Any help is welcome.
Thanks,
Pat.

Answer (score 0):

[From Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference), 422 means:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity    invalid_params  
                            request failed, validate parameters try again
422 Unprocessable Entity    verification_needed     
                            request failed, enter billing information in the Heroku Dashboard before utilizing resources.
```

So double-check your parameters embedded [in your slug](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#slug) (the snapshot of your application code that is ready to run on the platform)

Comment: Could it be that my slug is now too large for my Dynos (2X)? How to be sure?  A better error message would be helpfull there...  BTW, there is a huge price difference to go for next size.  Do I need to start considering a new host?

Comment: @PatCappelaere to be sure, try with, just for testing, a smaller slug.